# Can Mail warn when emailing certain addresses?

Tags: snow-leopard, email, contacts

I have my own personal mail account (a gmail account) and my academic email account (a university account) as different profiles on my Mail application in OS X Snow Leopard. I sometimes forget to switch the outgoing account to my university account when emailing my students and it will send from my gmail account instead. This is not a *huge* deal but I would prefer to have my students never get mail from my gmail account.

Is there a way to have Mail warn you when sending to a certain address (or an address that has a certain keyward in it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have Mail put certain addresses in the to field in black and all others in red.
I use this to have Mail flag email that's going outside my organization.

Do this by going to Preferences > Composing.
Then under the "Addressing" header check "Mark addresses not ending with [ ]."  Inside the box put ".nameofyourschool.edu".
Then every email address destined within your school will be black, and all others will be red.
Just the thing to ensure FERPA compliance.

Comment: interesting feature, but if i understand it correctly, it is not what i am asking for. no matter which email address i send it from, @<myschool>.edu is red. i am hoping for something to show up ONLY if i am mailing to @<myschool>.edu but i am mailing it from my gmail account. as it stands, there is still no way to be alerted if i am mailing from my gmail account or my school account when i am mailing TO a school account.

Comment: Well, your from: address will be RED if it is gmail and BLACK if it is @<yourschool>.edu.